How to explicitly enable tagging in R markdown/Quarto
I am working an a Quarto document that needs to have accessibility features, including tagging. I thought Quarto/R Markdown documents were implicitly tagged, but upon testing the rendered PDF in Adobe, there were no tags. How do I enable tagging in a Quarto document?

Do you have an example? what do you mean tag? you can insert HTML tags in rmarkdown, I know if you did a distill blog, you can tag articles to relate to keyboard/topics
